# Trouble Linking Git Homebrew

Tags: git, homebrew

When I run brew doctor, this is the error that I get first:

```
Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:

    git
```

**Things I've already tried**: 
I also tried to put `brew link git`, and I got this Error:

```
Error: Could not symlink share/git-core/contrib
/usr/local/share/git-core is not writable.
```

I tried using `brew link --overwrite git`, and it came back with:

```
Error: Could not symlink share/git-core/contrib
/usr/local/share/git-core is not writable.
```

I tried using `brew upgrade`, and `brew update`, and nothing happened.

Comment: You need more privileges (i.e. `sudo`).

Comment: I tried using sudo, and I got this reply. Error: Cowardly refusing to `sudo brew link`
You can use brew with sudo, but only if the brew executable is owned by root. However, this is both not recommended and completely unsupported so do so at your own risk.

Comment: You need to change the permissions on `/usr/local/share` so that you can write files into it (it needs to be writable and probably should also be readable and executable by you).

Answer (score 0):

in stead of installing git using homebrew download the official git-scm for mac and install it.

It should "overwrite" the problematic links and install the git properly.